# Solving IVPs with Heaviside function where switch depends on function value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, initial-value-problems

I am looking to solve an IVP of the format

$y'(t) = \begin{cases} 
      a, &   y(t) < y_0 \\
      b,  &   y_0 \le y(t) < y_1 \\
      c, &   y(t) \ge y_1 \\
   \end{cases}$

That is, the rate depends on the actual function value and switches stepwise between different constant values.

I have looked at using Laplace transforms (it's been a while!) but I am unsure how to use them when the switching is done using the function value and not as a value of $t$.

(for practical context, this is being used to control the feeding and consumption of bottles on a packing line)

Answer (score 1):

That definition divides the plane into three parts:

- $y < y_0$ (below green line in image below)
- $y_0 \le y < y_1$
- $ y \ge y_1$ (above pink line in image below)

For each part slopes $a$, $b$ and $c$ are required.

Here is a sketch of the situation for $a=1/2, b=2, c=1$:

[image: model]

For this situation it is possible to pick a continous $y(t)$, if one point $(t^*, y(t^*))$ is provided.

Comment: Thanks...this seems ridiculously simple now. Was completely overthinking this.

Comment: Are your $a$, $b$, $c$ of the same sign? E.g. a negative $b$ would liead to a slope field with zig-zags. One would probably need to remodel.

Comment: Varied signs. Can see how it would zig-zag, would not be difficult to do.

Comment: $y$ would stay constant more or less, the positive $a$ would lead into the middle zone, the negative $b$ would drive it back etc.

Comment: Rather, if $a>0>b$ and $y(0)<y_0$, the solution $y(\ )$ is defined only until it hits $y_0$. Note that even when $a>0$, $b>0$, the "solution" in the answer above does not solve the differential equation at the time $t_0$ when it crosses $y_0$ since it is not differentiable at time $t_0$.

Comment: @Did you are right from a mathematical point. I think I switched over to engineering mode. There are jumps at $y_0$ and $y_1$ for $y'$.

Comment: *Of course*, as long as $(a,b,c)$ have the same sign, these are entirely acceptable solutions from a physics/engineering point of view... My point was rather to stress that, when $a>0>b$, the picture of a solution rising to $y_0$ then making little excursions above $y_0$ in the "middle zone", coming back to $y_0$ again and again, was not correct.